# Exit if no active profile is set

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I exit from the application before any action is performed (especially bean creation) if there is no active profile?

I've done this with such configuration:

```
@Profile("default")
@Configuration
public class NoActiveProfileKiller {
    public NoActiveProfileKiller() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No active profile is selected");
    }
}
```

But this performs JPA actions at least.

Comment: In your application class (the one with the main method) you can check there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this with the next approach which uses a listener:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .listeners(new MyApplication())
            .sources(MyApplication.class)
            .run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        if (event.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles().length == 0) {
            LOGGER.error("No active profile is set. Will terminate");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider `SpringApplication.exit(...)` for a more graceful shutdown.

Comment: @helospark, there is no ApplicationContext yet

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(App.class);
        final SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
        // check if spring profile is set from outside.
        if (!source.containsProperty("spring.profiles.active") &&
            !System.getenv().containsKey("SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE")) {
            System.err.println("No Profile set, exiting");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does not work in case if you specify an active profile via application.properties

Comment: @ipergenitsa, if you specify active profiles in application.properties, you don't need the check anymore.